# glTexImage2D texture is not available for read in right format

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, opengl-es, raspberry-pi4, opengl-es-3.1

I am working on a cross-platform project that involves OpenGLES (3.1). While code executes perfectly on my `Windows` and `Ubuntu` machines. Running the same code on Raspberry PI 4 causes a strange issue, after successfully initializing texture with `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 16, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)` call, later in code requesting available reading type for same FrameBuffer `glGetIntegerv(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT, ...)` returns GL_GRBA. For context creation, I am using GLFW with GLAD. Below is the complete code of texture initialization:

```cpp
...
GLuint pix_buf;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &pix_buf);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pix_buf);
GLuint text;
glGenTextures(1, &text);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, text);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 16, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, text, 0);

GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    std::cout << "Frame buffer was not initialized" << std::endl;
    return;
}

GLint read_format, read_type;
glGetIntegerv(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT, &read_format);
glGetIntegerv(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE, &read_type);
...
```

- `read_format` value is equal to `GL_RGBA` which should be `GL_RGB`!
- `read_type` value is equal to `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as expected

So after rendering call attempt of reading texture to local *back_buf* array using: `glReadPixels(0, 0, 16, 256, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, back_buf)` is causing `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` with `glReadPixels(invalid format GL_RGB and/or GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)`. Changing reading type from `GL_RGB` to `GL_RGBA` is fixing error but resulting data format cant be used by my program (I strictly am looking for GL_RGB format).

My question is am I doing something wrong or there is a problem with Raspberry PI 4 OpenGLES drivers?

Comment: The lack of any calls to `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` is suspicious. Who's to say the attachment of the texture to the framebuffer succeeded or not?

Comment: @Frank, Sorry this was a typo, in the original code, I am checking status and everything seems to be ok with that. I edited post to add `glCheckFramebufferStatus()`